# Where is the best place to get reviews on hosting providers?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

I know this is very subjective, but I really need reliable reviews of hosting providers. Thank you for not downvoting :]

Comment: What kind of hosting? What kind of review? Which criteria to compare?

Comment: Generic Web Hosting. A good review?

Comment: Anywhere but here.

Comment: Just "good" is anything but objective. How would anyone know what you consider "good"?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the [Web Hosting Talk forums](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/) for colo/hosting provider recommendations and reviews.

Answer (score 0):

There are no reliable, or good hosting providers.  They're like tax accountants or lawyers; fine when you're doing what they say, but at some point they'll bite you in the ass.

;)